# How to group by column having spelling mistakes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, soundex

While working with some legacy data, I want to group the data on a column ignoring spelling mistakes. I think SOUNDEX() could do the job to achieve the desired result. Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT soundex(AREA)
FROM MASTER
GROUP BY soundex(AREA)
ORDER BY soundex(AREA)
```

But (obviously) the SOUNDEX returned 4-character code in result rows like this, loosing actual strings:

```
A131
A200
A236
```

How could I include at least one occurrence from the group into the query result instead of 4-character code.

Comment: using MIN (or MAX) AREA would do the trick as answered by flaschenpost.

Comment: +1 For a clear question and teaching me about a function I didn't know existed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT soundex(AREA) as snd_AREA, min(AREA) as AREA_EXAMPLE_1, max(AREA) as AREA_EXAMPLE_2
from MASTER
group by soundex(AREA)
order by AREA_EXAMPLE_1
;
```

In MySQL you could select group_concat(distinct AREA) as list_area to get all the versions, and I don't know about that in SQL-Server, but min and max give two examples of the areas, and you wanted to discard the diffs anyway.

Comment: It worked but with astonishing results. For e.g., the soundex() is grouping the NORTH NAZ and NORTH KAR, P.I.B. and P.E.C.H, SHAH FAISAL and S.I.T.E as same. ??? !!!!

Comment: Maybe you could control the soundex- function in SQL-Server. I only have access to MySQL and there I get soundex("NORTH NAZ") = N6352, soundex("NORTH KAR" = N6326. Or maybe there are even different soundex-functions availiable.

Comment: I tried removing spaces from the string (NORTHNAZ and NORTHKAR), but actually the SOUNDEX() is matching too loosely. For example, following strings produce same SOUNDEX codes;

<<< select SOUNDEX(col1), col1
from
(
select 'GULBAHAR' as col1
union ALL
select 'GULBERG'
) t >>> ** 

<<< select SOUNDEX(col1), col1
from
(
select 'GULSHANEIQBAL' as col1
union ALL
select 'GULSHANEMAYMAR'
) t >>> **

Any idea, or I have to create new thread for this another issue?

Answer (score 5):

You could also use `row_number()` to get one row for each `soundex(area)` value:

```
select AREA, snd
from
(
  select AREA, soundex(AREA) snd,
    row_number() over(partition by soundex(AREA)
                      order by soundex(AREA)) rn
  from master
) x
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/568e3/4)

Comment: Your solution wouldn't include any occurrence from the group. I didn't want row number.

Comment: @Ali.NET You requested to receive one value from each group which this does. Did you see the demo?